# jquery: auto-size absolute-positioned child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout

i'm having the following markup using 2 divs. the #child div has set position:absolute;

```
+------------------------------+
|    +----------+              |
|    | #child   |              |
|    +----------+              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
+------------------------------+
```

i want to change the child's height by code so that it always auto-sizes to its container like this:

```
+------------------------------+
|    +----------+              |
|    | #child   |              |
|    |          |              |
|    |          |              |
|    |          |              |
|    +----------+              |
+------------------------------+
```

is there a default function for it?
thx

Comment: jquery isn't necessary for this. Pure CSS can do it. See my answer.

Comment: only issue with css is that 100% height on elements doesn't work in all browsers

Comment: 100% page height has issues on certain versions of IE. Other than that CSS is preferable to Javascript for this and will result in a *much* better user experience. If anything you should use CSS where you can and Javascript/jQuery in those few cases where CSS won't work (which you can detect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try;

```
$('#child').height($('#child').parent().height());
```

this assumes that you have no padding and borders on your outer div. if you do you will need to take these off the height in some browsers to ensure it matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

with:

```
#parent { position: relative; background: red; height: 500px; width: 700px; }
#child { position: absolute; background: yellow; height: 80%; top: 10%; bottom: 10; left: 100px; width: 300px; }
```

**Note:** the child's height is relative (80%) to the parent's height so no matter what you set the height of the parent to or dynamically resize it to, it'll change the height of the child but the parent must have an explicitly set height (even if its 100%) or this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (rough approximation, adjust to your needs)

```
$('#child').css('left', '20%').css('top','10%').css('height','80%').css('width', '30%');
```

Comment: This would size the child div relative to the page size, not the parent div.

Comment: @James Goodwin: uh? it would set the child relative to the parent div, not the page.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking for some reason because it was absolute it would use the height of the page instead, but in fact you are right! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged with jQuery I will provide you with a jQuery style solution too:

```
$("#child").height($("#parent").height()*0.8);
```